# How do I make one div static and the second div scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two div in the same container. Div A has content and While Div B has an Image. While scrolling, I want DIV a content to be static and DIV B image should scroll. E.G https://sassiholford.com/shop/separates/dunster-shorts/

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't [post a link to an external website](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it/254430#254430). Instead, try and provide a [minimal reproduceable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you with your code.

Comment: You can use ```position: sticky;``` on this element. More can be found on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 1):

The left side uses `position: sticky` and the right just scrolls normally.

Alternatively you can use `position: fixed` and add it with a class using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `position: sticky;` to do this.

Here's an example: https://codepen.io/nickunjchopra/pen/ZEebQPV

Check out how I've set `div.left` to `position: sticky;`

Also note that `position: sticky;` doesn't work unless you have at least one of the `top, left, bottom, right` properties defined.

You can find more information on: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp

Comment: I am really not getting it, I had to recreate your code to exactly how my code is , but its not working.   https://codepen.io/nickunjchopra/pen/ZEebQPV

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

codepen: https://codepen.io/jon424/pen/XWMmXBO

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div-a">Div A Content</div>
  <div class="div-b"><img src="https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/86-868295_freetoedit-tumblr-random-thesimpsons-lisasimpson-lisa-simpson-png.png" alt="Lisa Simpson" width="500"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.div-a {
  position: fixed ;
}
```